# How to serialize a nested attribute from the result of a method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, active-model-serializers

I have 3 models User, Contract, and History.

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :histories
  has_many :contracts, through: :histories
end
```

Contract model:

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories
  has_many :users, through: :histories
end
```

History model:

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contract
end
```

I'm working with an API application and with Active Model Serializer gem. In the UserSerializer I have a method to get a specific collection of contracts like so:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :authentication_token, :current_contracts

  def current_contracts
    object.contracts.find_all{ |contract| contract.current_owner == object.id }
  end
end
```

The method works but the result is a collection of contracts with no history. Even though my contract serializer has this association in it:

```
class ContractSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :blockchain_id, :created_at, :product_name, :product_info, :price, :histories
  has_many :histories
end
```

The desired result is to be able to call the `current_contracts` method then be able to serialize `contract.histories` from that collection.

Is there any other way I could be approaching this?

Comment: `find_all` returns an array, and I'm guessing `ActiveModel::Serializer` doesn't like that. what happens when you just return `object.contracts` in `current_contracts`?

Comment: Hey Josh. I need that method since I don't need all the user.contracts i just need the contracts that meet the condition in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying `UserSerializer` like this:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :authentication_token
  has_many :current_contracts, each_serializer: ContractSerializer

  def current_contracts
    object.contracts.find_all{ |contract| contract.current_owner == object.id }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Aetherus exactly what I was looking for.